# root domain running wordpress and django application on app subdomain - proxy pages from app subdomain to main domain

Tags: django, wordpress, nginx

I have a Saas website that is developed using Django and the marketing site is also hand coded and running under django.

I would like to move the marketing site on the main domain to wordpress and then host the web application under an app subdomain.

However a number of pages that are important to our SEO are generated by the web application and appear on the main domain now.

eg.

example.com/service_page_1

example.com/service_page_2

Once I move the application to a subdomain these will be available at:

app.example.com/service_page_1

app.example.com/service_page_2

Is there a way example.com can be running a wordpress marketing site and these pages from the subdomain can be made available on the main domain?

I thought about hosting the content in iframes on the wordpress site but I am not sure how this would affect SEO.

The web application will be running behind an nginx web server.

Is there a way to proxy calls to certain routes on wordpress to my web application running behind nginx? (eg. [www.example.com/service/*/](http://www.example.com/service/*/) to display the page from my web application at app.example.com/service/*/)

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good idea. I don't think it will even maintain your SEO rankings like you hope. Why can't you just replicate the pages on your new WordPress site at the main domain and get rid of them from the subdomain when you're happy the new pages are showing up in SERPs?

Comment: A few reasons: 1. The page are also available to users of the application on the subdomain and some of them have additional data for logged in users. 2. The data for the pages is sitting inside a postgres database (and I am not sure about using that from wordpress). 3. I don't want to maintain a django and wordpress version of these pages.  I could make an API available from the app domain and use that to build new pages in wordpress though.  Why would it be a bad idea to proxy the pages from the app domain to the main domain?

Comment: I wouldn't use iframes here. It will be bad for SEO, bad user experience, bad on mobile. Also note that duplicate content across the two domains is potentially bad for SEO too. It sounds to me like you have two different usages of this page going on - one for marketing and one for logged in users. I know you don't want to maintain two separate versions of the page, but if they are that similar I think you need to properly rethink what your original goal of providing these pages is, to both sets of users. Architect a proper solution with two separate pages, not hack your original thing.

Comment: Why can't you create an app page which specifically does a job for logged in users, as well as linking to the marketing page on the other domain which contains more information? Could your app pull content from the WordPress database and display it? Again, I'm not sure this is a good idea and you might run into a situation where content changes in WordPress break your the other page on your app. Consider whenever you make changes on the marketing site you will always need to worry about how it affects the app page, or someone may not even realise they are breaking that page with their changes.

Comment: @BadHorsie, thanks for your comments. I won't use iframes at this stage as I have the same concerns as you.  I could look at generating data via a json api that wordpress calls and reproduce the page in wordpress.   I would have expected it to be quite simple to proxy a call to domain/service1 to app.domain/service1 though.  I have done something very similar on nginx where I am proxying the current wordpress blog running at blog.example.com to example.com/blog/.

Comment: Yes it's probably technically achievable in a few ways, such as with your server configuration, or using PHP or cURL or something to get the content, I just don't know if you're really solving your SEO concerns or creating more headaches down the line with maintenance and bugs. My gut feeling is this is really messy. We have the exact same setup you're describing at my company - a WordPress marketing site on the main domain, and a web app for users under a subdomain, and I can't think of why we would need to do what you're suggesting, or how in a nice, maintainable way.